# How to make a Asp.Net WebAPI 2 SPA (AngularJS) and Google Calendar API work together (authentication)?

Tags: c#, asp.net, angularjs, asp.net-web-api, google-calendar-api

I have an ASP.NET WebAPI 2 SPA with AngularJS, based on [this](http://bitoftech.net/2014/08/11/asp-net-web-api-2-external-logins-social-logins-facebook-google-angularjs-app/) sample, with social logins working already. The Google API's Authentication [docs](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/dotnet/guide/aaa_oauth) just states about Console apps or ASP.NET MVC applications, not Web API's. I just want my SPA to perform CRUD operations on Calendar.

I've seen a lot of examples for ASP.NET MVC, but none for WebAPI 1/2...

I'm trying to accomplish the authentication workflow, like we have with social logins, for Google Calendar API, enabling my app to add, remove and edit events on user calendar.

There is an example on how to perform the authentication/authorization workflow with plain Javascript. Do I need to do the Javascript workflow (adapting it for AngularJS)? If not, Is there a way of doing this with WebAPI2?

Could some one point me a direction on how to accomplish that?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Take a look at this example http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1009648/MVC-Angular-JS-CRUD-using-WEB-API-with-Stored-Proc

Comment: Thank you for the comment @Dimi, this is a nice article, but I think I couldn't find anything related to Google Calendar API, or anything similar to that...

Comment: I am sure Google API it is like an other WebAPI it is baes on GET y POST basically. Just try to experiment a little bit.

Comment: You're mixing with lots of different frameworks, I suggest finding what you're trying accomplish and then picking the technology that would fit the purpose. I suggest the Javascript [Quickstart](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/quickstart/js) is a great way to start off. Hope this helps and Good luck! :)